# Ubuntu 15.04 systemd vs upstart

Tags: boot, 15.04, upstart, services, systemd

Unlike the prior versions Ubuntu 15.04 now uses `systemd` instead of `upstart`. To start programs at boot I always created conf-files in `/etc/init/`. They would look like this:

```
start on login-session-start
script
/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0  -display :0  -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass  -rfbport 5900  -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -forever -bg  -o /var/log/x11vnc.log
end script
```

Unfortunately, this does not work anymore in Ubuntu 15.04 and I was trying to find an equivalent to this conf-file that runs with systemd. Though the internet wasn't yet quite so resourceful.

What is necessary to start the above conf-file at boot? Are there translators between upstart and systemd?

Comment: Side note (sort of): Does it need to run as root, or can it be run as a user?

Comment: Well, I wanna connect through vnc without being dependent on a certain user which is why I run it as root. Is that of any matter in relation to systemd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to, you can instead make a systemd `.service` file that does the same thing. A basic systemd `.service` file for the above command might look like the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start VNC server
Requires=lightdm.service
After=lightdm.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0  -display :0  -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass  -rfbport 5900  -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -forever

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Things to note:

- Because this service relies on lightdm starting up, I've added a `Requires=lightdm.service`. This means that if this service is requested to start, then `lightdm.service` will also be asked to start, but if `lightdm.service` fails to start, then this service won't be asked to start. Additionally, `After=lightdm.service` is needed so that this service will start after `lightdm.service has finished starting.
- The command being run doesn't have `-bg` specified. In systemd, it's preferred that services stay in the foreground, so that systemd knows that they are running. Note that it *is* possible to specify a PID file for a service that goes into the background.
- `WantedBy=graphical.target` specifies that, as part of starting up your GUI, this should also get started up.

To install this file so that the service is run as root, add this file into `/etc/systemd/system`. Then, run `sudo systemctl enable <filename>` (where `<filename>` is the name of the service file in `/etc/systemd/system`). A symlink should be created in `/etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/`. After rebooting, when you run `systemctl status <filename>`, you should see that the service is recognized and not yet started.

Note that `/etc/systemd/system/` is meant for system-wide services that the system administrator (you) add. `/lib/systemd/system/` is meant for system-wide services installed by packages. You do not need to make a symlink to `/lib/systemd/system/` for the service to load. The below table (taken from the `systemd.unit` manpage) describes what each location is for with regards to system services (there are separate paths for user services):

```
   ┌────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────┐
   │Path                │ Description                 │
   ├────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┤
   │/etc/systemd/system │ Local configuration         │
   ├────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┤
   │/run/systemd/system │ Runtime units               │
   ├────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┤
   │/lib/systemd/system │ Units of installed packages │
   └────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Created file `/lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service` with your above content, created link `/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service -> /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service`. But after booting the service does not run. `systemctl status x11vnc.service` leads to: `Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service; linked; vendor preset: enabled)` and `Active: inactive (dead)`

Comment: @Socrates: What's the output of `systemctl status graphical.target`? Is there a symlink to your service in `/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/`? (Don't create one manually if it doesn't exist; it means something's wrong with the configuration.)

Comment: `systemctl status graphical.target`: `Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target; static; vendor preset: enabled)` and `Active: active since Di 2015-06-16 04:08:01 CEST; 2min 39s ago`. The only link in `/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants` is `systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service -> ../systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service`.

Comment: @Socrates: See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, moved the file `x11vnc.service` to `/etc/systemd/system` and ran `sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service`.

Comment: After reboot `systemctl status x11vnc.service` returns `Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)` and `Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Di 2015-06-16 04:40:08 CEST; 10min ago` and `Process: 818 ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -display :0 -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -forever (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`and `Main PID: 818 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`.

Comment: Looks to me as if it wasn't run by `root` and therefore ran into the failure.

Comment: @Socrates: odd. The default user should be `root`. In the `[Service]` section, add `User=root`. Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl start x11vnc` (no need to restart).

Comment: `sudo systemctl start x11vnc` runs the vnc server perfectly fine both, with and without `User=root` in `[Service]`. But the vnc server is not run after reboot resulting in the above error.

Comment: Can you add in `After=lightdm.service` in the `[Unit]` section and restart your computer?

Comment: I've edited the service file above slightly (changed `Wants` to `Requires`). You may want to make this change in your service file as well.