# Lubuntu 15.10 systemd vs upstart kiosk script

Tags: lubuntu, 15.10, upstart, systemd, kiosk

Quite similar question that has been discussed [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636899/ubuntu-15-04-systemd-vs-upstart) regarding the change of the default init daemon from Upstart to Systemd and converting foo.conf to foo.service for Systemd to be able to work with.

Code snippet that can be found on the net, allowing kiosk PC to boot right into the browser under openbox-session without login:

```
#/etc/init/foo.conf

start on (filesystem and stopped udevtrigger) 
stop on runlevel [06]

emits starting-x
respawn

exec sudo -u $USER startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/foo.sh --
```

and

```
#/opt/foo.sh

#!/bin/bash

xset -dpms
xset s off
openbox-session &

while true; do
    firefox -P myProfile
done
```

We know that

```
exec sudo -u $USER startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/foo.sh --
```

can be "translated" into

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec "exec sudo -u $USER startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/foo.sh --"
```

and according to [THIS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers), "respawn" goes under Service section too, so it give us:

```
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec "exec sudo -u $USER startx /etc/X11/Xsession
```

but what to do with "start on, stop on and emits" things?
and do we need any "requires / after" directives?

Testing on Lubuntu 15.10.