# Migrate Upstart to SystemD on Ubuntu/Lubuntu to autostart Chrome

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, google-chrome, systemd

This is very similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705863/lubuntu-15-10-systemd-vs-upstart-kiosk-script) but it did not receive any answers.

I'm migrating from Lubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and have a simple upstart script I need to convert to systemd. It starts Chrome in OpenBox as was sourced from : [Converting an existing Ubuntu Desktop into a Chrome kiosk](https://thepcspy.com/read/converting-ubuntu-desktop-to-kiosk/)

It creates an upstart script which starts an X11 session with kiosk.sh:

```
start on (filesystem and stopped udevtrigger)
stop on runlevel [06]

emits starting-x
respawn

exec sudo -u $USER startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sh --
```

kiosk.sh then does the following to launch openbox and chrome:

```
#!/bin/bash

xset -dpms
xset s off
openbox-session &

while true; do
    rm -rf ~/.{config,cache}/google-chrome/
    google-chrome --kiosk --no-first-run  'http://thepcspy.com'
done
```

What would the best approach be to achieve the same using systemd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the kiosk.sh. Systemd is able to execute shell scripts. Create a file called "chromestart.service" inside "/etc/systemd/system/" and enter this contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start of Google Chrome on startup

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sh
User=ENTER USERNAME HERE
Group=ENTER GROUPNAME HERE (usually the same as username)

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After saving this file, run this command to enable the service on startup:

```
systemctl enable chromestart.service
```

Also recommended would be to set the correct permissions:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/systemd/system/chromestart.service
sudo chmod 755 /etc/systemd/system/chromestart.service
```

Now reboot.

Comment: Don't forget to either reboot or enter systemctl start chromestart.service

Comment: @RoryO'Siochain The answer has been updated regarding the script getting executed now includes startx. Sudo isn't needed because the user and group can be set in SystemD.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Have been very busy! It turns out that your answer is correct but that 16.04 doesn't come with startx installed. sudo apt-get install xinit, then create ~/.xinitrc with exec openbox-session on the first line of the file. I'll write up a clearer answer but keep yours as accepted because it answers the question asked.